# How do I configure freeglut to work with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, freeglut

I would like to know how to configure freeglut to work with the Code::Blocks IDE and minGW compiler. I don't have much experience with Code::Blocks and I have tried both glut and freeglut for ages.
Any help would be appreciated, including tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [tutorial](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~goetz/codeblocks/glut/) which shows how to install glut.  I was able to use it to configure freeglut as well.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this tutorial a while back. They will be including it in an upcoming version of code::blocks so it will eventually make this tutorial obsolete. But for now, you can run this tutorial just fine. Remember Glut / Glut32 in general are OLD ( 2001 ) propriatary libraries. But freeGlut is always up to date. So its better to use freeGlut instead.

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_FreeGlut_with_Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial which tells step by step with images to solve all problems in configuration
[Configure codeblocks with Freeglut Opengl](http://www.thetechsol.com/2015/03/how-to-configure-freeglut-opengl.html)

Hope This Will Helpful..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer paying attention to the part titled 'Provide context for links'. You should provide at the least quote relevant parts of the link which pertain to this answer in the event the link becomes unavailable.